# max possible number of dice throw

Tags: probability

Scott repeatedly rolls a pair of standard six-sided dice and keeps track of the
sum of the two numbers rolled each time. So far he has not rolled any sum
twice. What is the maximum possible number of times he has thrown the dice?

Answer (score 1):

So there are

> 11 different outcomes for 6-sided pairs of dice, from 2 to 12. He could therefore have rolled the dice a maximum of 11 different times to get each of the different outcomes exactly once.